# How do I disconnect a user in Voximplant from logged_in status?

Tags: voximplant

The client state is logged_in. How can I disconnect a user state from voximplant side because I want to login again loginwithpassword() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use client.disconnect() method
https://voximplant.com/docs/references/reactnative/voximplant/client#disconnect